# Internet Explorer Button simple behavior needs enabling ActiveX controls?

Tags: html, onmouseover

I have a button whose text color changes when the mouse is over it.
The HTML is :

```
<a href="products.html" style="text-decoration:none">
     <div
          class="button"
          onmouseover="this.style.color='black'"
          onmouseout="this.style.color='#666666'"><div class="menu_text">Products</div></div></a>
```

The thing is when I opened the page in IE8 , IE8 says:

> To protect your security IE8 has restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer.

in the information bar.

I click on options  and allow blocked content.
Then it works fine.

**Fancybox** and **GalleryView** Plugins that I've included in my pages also are seen only when blocked content is allowed.

Is there a way to fix this?

I find that such an issue does not show [here](http://www.janitha.com) in the navigation bar buttons(home,random,about...). Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IE blocks scripts when running websites locally - that is, from local file system. The warning should not appear when running on the server or on localhost.

See here: [How do you avoid the drop-down ActiveX warning in IE7 and IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007037/how-do-you-avoid-the-drop-down-activex-warning-in-ie7-and-ie8)

Comment: so long as it doesn't happen on server,I'll be fine. Thank You.